# Can the regularity argument for the solution of a parabolic PDE in Pinsky's paper be generalized?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

[In this paper](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272398/1-s2.0-S0022039600X00290/1-s2.0-S0022039600937719/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEMP%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIHiZiLDiZgXLiyCI1wZxM0ENeg2uMz5JTSRt3R%2FeFkMuAiEA1%2Fr08qb%2FQfpof8cXae9y3AffJ%2B55JIlGmASdOEI8CoUqvAUI6%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARAFGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDDu696y%2BMhdwSra1WiqQBT04rRtFUuj4fRtlaOmSQT3CMPJKknLcAxSzzi3Yafzd%2FB8BNjmW8%2F5c8cldRXg2AJAf20MXJou1%2BdormkK9RLYwcdFMcK%2Fzydapdf5f3J%2Flttn5ZoelQBOVymJ%2BpTqckSbNtduz00oeQReLog2sEpxRSJoZh30XGNBgdbW%2BvKqc0XoAD4g%2FFPGblUPNSpPb89%2BmBbxGMgcjWi3Wt99EGfkuEZPa0iSpjqOaqQcRxSLwWGN6x8QfdOy1zQaxk0VoPIMnBXKBvZ3RBDQsOqHD%2B0DR7QfU601UHOSM4x%2Fm561TVhLAdcLiQAXKgc%2FgvzaNDwAxqnaRzc9lpLpBjNXrNPUCU99pmAVAgnYSatmoEzwjue8xowEpKNJuCxC1lzxNODMTeXXwriDjkMAvw9hI4oFWAse8z%2BleLSsvr6xhme3dxtbeJ7A61hmR1vMafVEWTad7DMKy2h1w73r1fFc0V%2BZjyd8T9LgAG3jOdFMwgnJxqHrxplDYUQG37lyRGcNAbhqrDdq7GyjTTG1OXHHZYwLvOya16ITZf0mvbb8TST%2BVmBLMUTI8COgz1bYKiziRhRECnPqEvl0VmqEkYG2NcAyI7wUrAMKWeETjZqP0YHPSZaTU1Sbu3xEwk5D%2FosfPtnNFt1vmk04bbesQO9oXv4yXavLXAmgyZPNZpBaupsL6oF8sVM3LRzRUE4l9NYrnAlGq7pw2kLL7wPbTHu%2FePwaZb6Jo%2BgMzm4gD5YmkSUzhUOtpZIecNP%2BlIEsDFcatY%2FjnTh%2Fu1VeyrGczzSz58Prx7e7Pp0MnOqf1eGcbZpCzAyYmsKKcxiAXGLMCr4EkIqGpnHBLlzyzl%2BJxtbLQY%2Bthf2fVHb43B%2FG4WrWkcNy%2FMJijg6oGOrEBdw6YupRsbI4AQt3eHJDb6%2Bqg3undS9wPcSUigYJHqbnelXZ5YTWECGj1pvW2X9f4zN63b2svY02EJEulz97IqHJjGRLtFEeX5MgQ5SmujbnxgfmfeL0yKNVimSgNCw6LH1C1W%2FGIoRcSaEuDvfiR2nbJCiE0%2BrdY7ubCx70WRJV%2Bmdcmxw6h0wz5ZPvZL4v%2BAWeEKct12OtrqCGytN3JuXMB%2FlqMmps43G7B%2FmYh8o8T&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20231031T104822Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=299&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYSNNQBPT6%2F20231031%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=c5429db08b4cbbaee936b6f5f8a60d5e433773874473381380d1157c2d5b4506&hash=76e0be7f6698c51285a2bb048655124cb18d2239bb79291990dbb71668152761&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0022039600937719&tid=spdf-51c6d1d7-95c4-4e33-ac19-7a85d9477516&sid=875e644141ffb544fc6b7bc4161d8d080b24gxrqa&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=0413585e0b00505d5051&rr=81eb5341a8492630&cc=br) Pinsky shows existence, uniqueness and regularity for the problem
$$
u_t=\Delta u-a(x) u^p |\nabla u|^q
$$
where $a\in C^2( \mathbb{R}^d)$ satisfies the condition $ a(x)|\leq (1+|x|^2)^N$.

His idea is to consider an approximation of the problem in the form
$$
u_t=\Delta u-a(x)(1+\delta|x|^2)^{-N} (u+\varepsilon)^p |\nabla u| ^q
$$ and then suppress the dependence on $\delta$ and $\varepsilon$.
 I'm interested in getting a good understanding of the regularity argument. He defined
$$
\beta (x) = a(x)(1+\delta|x|^2)^{-N},
$$ which by hypothesis is a bounded function, and due to (2.7) in the reference linked, it follows that $u$ and $|\nabla u|$ are bounded. Then using the definition of $\nabla u$ as a mild solution, he proves the estimate
$$
\begin{split}
|\nabla u(x+z,t) - \nabla (x,t)| & \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}p(t,x,y)|\nabla \phi(y+z) -\nabla \phi (y)|dy \\ &\quad+ c \int_{0}^t \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}| \nabla_x p(s,x+z,y) - \nabla_x p(s,x,y)|dyds
\end{split}
$$
where $p(t,x,y)$ is the Heat Kernel in $\mathbb{R}^d$. He then  estimates this last integral by
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}| \nabla_x p(s,x+z,y) - \nabla_x p(s,x,y)|dy \leq Kt^{-(1+\alpha)/2}|z|^{\alpha} \mbox { with }0<\alpha<1. $$
He cites [Ben Artzi's article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0362546X92902209) for this last estimate. In fact in his proposition 2.4, equation (2.11) he directly gives the above inequality saying only that he is interpolating in (2.6). I don't know what this interpolation argument he used means, I don't know if it is the Mean Value Theorem that he is using in the gradient, as he got this $0<\alpha<1$ moreover I don't know how. I would be grateful if someone could explain me! After that he concludes the argument using a standard parabolic regularity result.

Another question I was thinking about is the following. If this interpolation step is proved by using the Mean Value Theorem, essentially the limitation is
$$ 
\begin{split}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}| \nabla_x p(s,x+z,y) & - \nabla_x p(s,x,y)|dy \\
&\approx \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |\nabla_x^2 p(s,x+z ,y)||z| dy \\
&\approx |z| \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |\nabla_x^2 p(s,x+z,y)| dy.
\end{split}
$$
It is known that the Hessian of the heat kernel is normally limited by the heat kernel itself, that is
$$
|\nabla_x^2 p(s,x+z,y)| \leq Cs^{-1} p(2s,x+z,y)
$$ (according to [this MathOverflow Q&A](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457448/estimative-for-hessian-of-heat-kernel-in-mathbbrd)). So my second doubt is whether this regularity step could be done differently in more general cases, Imagine that $a(x)=|x|^{-N}$ and if it is possible to find the existence of a solution such that $u $ and $|\nabla u|$ are limited. The change would occur here in the part where the kernel gradients are estimated
$$ 
\begin{split}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}| \nabla_x p(s,x+z,y) & - \nabla_x p(s,x,y)||y|^{-N}dy \\
& \approx |z| \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |\nabla_x^2 p(s,x+z,y)||y|^{-N} dy \\
& \approx |z|Cs^{-1} \int_{ \mathbb{R}^d} |p(2s,x+z,y)||y|^{-N} dy.
\end{split}
$$
But the last integral can be convergent if $N<d$. I have doubts whether this thought is correct, as I have seen papers that say if the nonlinearity has a singularity, the solution cannot be classical. I appreciate any suggestions and comments.